# Flutter How to make a Text widget in a Wrap widget start from the end of the previous widget and not start bellow the previous widget?

Tags: flutter, text

I'm trying to make a complete the sentence user interface that may overflow to the next line like this example:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 Wrap(
   spacing: 0.8,
   runSpacing: 4.0,
   children: <Widget>[
     new Text('Alpha '),
     new Container(
       width: 50,
       height: 19,
       child: new TextField(
          style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
          ),
       ),
     ),
     new Text(' charlie all the node in jank list is out of time all the node in jank list is out of time',)
   ],
 )
```

This is the **current** outcome:
[image]

How do I get the second string to start from the end of the TextField and overflow to the next line?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really interesting question and quite challenging, I found a solution by using Text rich and text span to achieve it. Hope it helps!

[image]

```
          Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Alpha ',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              children: <InlineSpan>[
                WidgetSpan(
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.baseline,
                  baseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 19,
                    child: TextField(
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text:
                      ' charlie all the node in jank list is out of time all the node in jank list is out of time',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```